# Where is IActionResult for WebAPI 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-hosting

I am implementing WebAPI 2 self hosting in an Console Application.

I have include the packages below from NuGET:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost

I have also read that WebAPI 2 should returns `IActionResult` instead of `IHttpActionResult`.

However, I have been searching around for whole day, do not know which assembly or nugget package this `IActionResult` reside in. :(

Comment: asp.net-core uses `IActionResult` while asp.net-web-api2 v5.2.3.0 uses `IHttpActionResult`

Comment: Nkosi, do I need to install these asp.net* assembly since this is a console application.

Comment: Yes. provided you want to use web api in self hosted owin. You have everything you need there. You were just looking for an interface that does not apply to the version of the framework you are using.

Comment: What version are you intending to use. Core or Web api2. In Core, mvc and web api have been merged into a common framework.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am still using V5.3.2.0.

Comment: @s_k glad to help. I've added the details of my comments as an  answer in case it resolves your question.

Answer (score 3):

asp.net-core uses `IActionResult` while asp.net-web-api2 v5.2.3.0 uses `IHttpActionResult`.

The NuGet packages you listed will allow you to implement WebAPI 2 Self Hosting using Owin in a Console Application.

In Asp.Net-Core, MVC and Web API have been merged into a common framework that replaces the abstract `ActionResult` and `IHttpActionResult` into the common `IActionResult`.